# Play framework : update messages without re-deploy

Tags: localization, playframework-2.0

how would you do to be able to change messages without having to stop the play instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that if your messages files are declared in common destination (and probably they are).

If you want to make it easier you need to put some additional work, for an example, you can use JavaScript for translating the labels, next you need to put these files OUTSIDE the public folder of the app, somewhere in the filesystem and access it with additional http server (otherwise it will require redeploying the app after each change).

off-topic:

In general I'm big advocate of serving static, public assets with frontend HTTP server instead of using the `assets.at...` method, thanks to this approach you are able to add/change/delete these assets without redeploying the application, and as we know images/scripts/styles are very often the subject to change. Finally you don't waste Play's resources for serving that stuff, and you are able to write advanced caching rulez with server's config (instead of 'fighting' with proper headers in Play's controllers)